# twitter typeahead.js not updating suggestions

Tags: typeahead.js

The problem I'm having is when I begin to type, the suggestions show but only in alphabetical order and don't update. Its as if its not filtering the results based on my input. As far as I can tell Im getting the data correctly. The json response is from The Echo Nest [here](http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/list_genres?api_key=JSSXGZIEPOLRS21K7&format=json). The information I'm after is the genres name from the json response which I'm getting.

```
var search = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: function(data) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(data.name); },
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                limit: 3,
                remote: {
                url:'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/list_genres?api_key= JSSXGZIEPOLRS21K7&format=json',
                        filter: function(search) {
                        return $.map(search.response.genres, function(data) { return {     name: data.name }; });
                        }
                }
 });

search.initialize();
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                name: 'genres',
                displayKey: 'name',
                source: search.ttAdapter()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o9pcso1u/1/

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question here. So it turned out I was using the wrong query. It should have been

`http//developer.echonest.com/api/v4/genre/search?api_key=JSSXGZIEPOLRS21K7&format=json&results=10&name=%QUERY`

where %QUERY is, what I'm guessing the text input field thats used by typeahead.js to search against. 
With the original query of:

`http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/list_genres?api_key= JSSXGZIEPOLRS21K7&format=json`

there was no where to add the %QUERY as it just returned a list and that list wasn't searchable with the above query.